# Ajax fetch column text from a populated data table and use it in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have a datatable from which I want to take the text from a clicked cell and use it as a variable in PHP, so that I use that variable to query mysql.  My codes so far as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready( function () {
     $('#priority tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
           var celldat = $(this).find('td:first').text(); //gets the text from the first column when a row is clicked.
           $.ajax({
              url: 'prioritize.php', //my url
              method: "POST",
              async: 'false',
              data: {variable:celldat},
              success: function(data) {
              alert(celldat); //The alert is perfect.  It returns the text from the first column.
                window.location.reload(true);
              }
        })
        });
     });
    </script>
```

In my PHP I am trying to echo the same value:

```
<?php
$selected=$_POST['variable']; 
echo $selected;
?>
```

But it is not working.  Essentially I want to use the `$selected` in mysql select query to populate another table.

Comment: Do you want like if selected text is `apple` , it should use `$apple` variable ?

Comment: @jagad89 I am not sure...as the variable keeps changing....the purpose is to capture the text from the table and save it as a php variable....

Comment: If you want to use the variable for next request, you should store this variable in `session` and then you can use this for next http request. 

If you want to send response in same , you already having data in variable and handle it.

Comment: you can message me [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/404532/jagad89) if you want to discuss in details.

Comment: if you say that `$selected` is fine, what's in the PHP part (that's not showed here) where you use it ? any query ?

Comment: @OldPadawan Yes I will use it in MySql select query.  And there is nothing more to php part in it.

Comment: Understood that :) my point is : `alert(celldat); //The alert is perfect` -> is `variable:celldat` caught by PHP when sent by Ajax ? did you try something on the PHP side ? ie: post data through Ajax, PHP echoes the data, check response on the page who originated the Ajax call ? it seems so unclear at this point...

Comment: @OldPadawan No I haven't tried much on the PHP side except for trying to get the value echoed through php...which didn't happen and hence stuck there....The alert is perfect means, the ajax alert pops out....but not getting posted in php nor php echoes...

Comment: try to modify your jQuery `success: function(data){alert(celldat);}` to `success: function(html){ alert(html);}` and PHP side `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); $selected = $_POST['variable']; echo"$selected";` if Ajax sends back the var you're ok, if not, let us know...

Comment: @OldPadawan  Many thanks...this sort of worked....I could see the complete HTML content populated in the alert along with the $selected value for sure...but when the page gets reloaded...the echo is missing... I am getting the following message `Notice: Undefined index: variable in /Users/WorkStation1545/Sites/MarketPulse/categories.php on line 42`

Answer (score 0):

in data: try to make it like this : `"data: {variable:"+celldat"}"`

Try to do this `$_POST['data']` this will give you all data sent from the ajax request

Answer (score 0):

Following the comments, you need to modify your jQuery

```
 success: function(data){ alert(celldat); }
```

to

```
 success: function(html){ alert(html); }
```

> PHP side

```
 <?php
 error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
 $selected = $_POST['variable']; 
 echo"$selected";
 ?>
```

You need to do something with the response, as, upon success, with the code you showed first, you just send the page to itself: update a div or table cell...
Ajax let you use the data sent back from PHP without refresh, why would you reload then ?

example of udating a div with PHP response:

```
success: function(html){ // 'html' is PHP response
   $("#responsediv").html(''+html+''); // update a div with ID 'responsediv'
   // as ID have to be unique, it makes sure you have the proper data in the correct div
    },
     error: function (request, status, error) { // handle error
      alert(request.responseText);
    }
```